# Use customized template from context menu

Tags: windows-explorer, microsoft-excel-2007, templates

I wanted to use a customized Excel template for **all** new files. Sure, I can create a new template in the templates folder and in Excel use `New` and select my template or double-click on the template file.

But I wanted to use that template also when I'm creating a new file from the Explorer context menu with mouse right click -> `Create New`. It takes always the built-in(?) template.

How can I get Excel and Windows Explorer to behave this way?

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this. Open the `C:\Windows\ShellNew` folder. There will be a Microsoft Excel file in there. It was called `EXCEL12.XLSX` on my machine with Office 2010, though I'll guess the number might change depending on the version of Office. Replace this file with whatever you want. You can even edit it in place.

Answer (score 1):

Save your template in the XLStart folder with the name book.xltx (as a template, extension depending on your version of excel).

XLStart folder can be found here:

Excel 2000 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\XLStart\

Excel XP - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 10\XLStart\

Excel 2003 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 11\XLStart\

***Excel 2007 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 12\XLStart***

Next time you open a new excel document, it will use this template.

Comment: I know this, but it does not work as expected. No clue.

Comment: Ok, for the right click menu, it might be linked to a different template in the registry. Try to follow the answer in this [link](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070111215540AA79PZA) . I assume for you, under the .xlsx filetype, there is already a filename. Change that to your template name and try again.

Comment: @PeterMmm can you inform us if this worked this way?